# how to select numbers that is not between double/single quotes with regular expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

hi i have problem selecting the numbers that is not in the single/double qoutes . let say we have this text below .

```
    <style color='#424242'></style>

123

    /* you can count this 5454 */

    <style color="#767676"></style>

8787
```

i want to select just the 123 and 8787 , nothing else 
how should i do this with regular expression in javascript

if i use \d in RegExp it w'll select all the numbers and i know that .
but i want to tell it that only select those numbers that is not surrounded by double/single/star .

Comment: Argh...this gets really complicated when you consider somebody writing the following: `var quoteCharacter = "\"";` or anything to that effect.

Comment: You shouldn't parse HTML with regexes. You should look in the DOM tree for nodes whose nodeValue contains the number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do that :

```
var numbers = str.split('"').filter(function(_,i){ return !(i%2) }).join('')
                 .split("'").filter(function(_,i){ return !(i%2) }).join('')
                 .match(/\d+/g);
```

The idea is to start by removing what is between quotes and then applying a regular expression.

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/olexib/1/edit) (open the console)

But, like any time HTML and regexes are mixed, you'll find cases where it doesn't work. So, if your use case isn't strictly controlled, you'd better parse, for example by applying a regex to `element.texContent||element.innerText`.

Comment: this specific code breaks horribly with single inside double and vice versa, as well as with escaped quotes. This needs more work, but the idea is sound.

Comment: aargh, `innerText` is a non-standard property that doesn't work in Firefox

Comment: Like it very much! What about finding some way of dealing with strings like `'Peters\'s hat'`? I am sure you will have a solution for that too ... ;-)

Comment: +1 . . . You pretty much gave my answer (using slightly different code), including the pitfalls of mixed quoting styles throughout the HTML.  Without strict coding standards, this exercise is somewhat precarious . . .

Comment: @cars10 for this case you could do a replacement of `\'` towards another char before the splitting and reverting after. But I'm afraid this will be more and more complex if OP want to handle any HTML.

Comment: im sorry , maybe it's stupid question to ask , but what is the first argument of the filter callback i know the filter has two argument filter(callback[, thisObject]); but what is this (_,i) ...

Comment: It's just a way to ignore the first parameter of the callback that I don't use. Naming _ the parameter is a convenient convention.

Comment: how should i stay on the first value , you are removing the text or numbers between any '' or "" that's mean if i had text like below

Comment: @MkDesign I'm sorry but I don't understand your comment.

Comment: you are removing the text or numbers between any '' or "" that's mean if i had text like this <style 'color:#424242'/> 424242 </style>  >this w'll change to>  <style ''/> 424242 </style> . i know it gave me the 424242 number but after that how should i replace it ? like text.replace(match_number,"<"+match_number+">") but this also change the number between single quotes ... i dont know if you get what i msaying

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not very cross-browser solution:

```
var iterator = document.evaluate(
    "descendant::text()",
    document.body, null,
    XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null),
node;
while (node = iterator.iterateNext()) {
    (node.nodeValue.match(/\d+/) || []).forEach(console.log);
}
```

Tested only in Firefox, but AFAIK, most browsers provide some XPath API, just look into the relevant documentation.